# Multiple image upload code does not working?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

My Photo Table is

```
Column Name Data Type   Constraint
PhotoID     Int         Primary key,auto increment
PhotoName   Varchar(100)    
ExtName     Varchar(100)    
PhotoType   Varchar(100)    
PhotoSize   Int 
TempleID    Int         Foreign key with templeinfo
```

and insertion procedure is

```
create proc [dbo].[prcTemplePhoto]
(
@PhotoName  Varchar(100),
@ExtName    Varchar(100),
@PhotoType  Varchar(100),
@PhotoSize  int,
@TempleID   Int
)
as
insert into TemplePhoto(PhotoName,ExtName,PhotoType,PhotoSize,TempleID) values (@PhotoName,@ExtName,@PhotoType,@PhotoSize,@TempleID)
select @@IDENTITY
```

I want to upload multiple photos at once for this i had copied code from internet

on designside

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbltemplepic" runat="server" Text="Temple Photo"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td id="fileUploadarea">
            <div>
                <div id="Div1">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="templeupload" runat="server" CssClass="fileUpload" /><br />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <input style="display: block;" id="btnAddMoreFiles" type="button" value="Add more images" onclick="AddMoreImages();" /><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnuplaod" runat="server"  Text="Upload" OnClick="btnuplaod_Click"  />
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<tr><td></td><td>
    <asp:Button ID="btninsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" OnClick="btninsert_Click"  />
    </td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblerror" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td><td></td></tr>
                   <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                       function AddMoreImages() {
                           if (!document.getElementById && !document.createElement)
                               return false;
                           var fileUploadarea = document.getElementById("fileUploadarea");
                           if (!fileUploadarea)
                               return false;
                           var newLine = document.createElement("br");
                           fileUploadarea.appendChild(newLine);
                           var newFile = document.createElement("input");
                           newFile.type = "file";
                           newFile.setAttribute("class", "fileUpload");

                           if (!AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId)
                               AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId = 100;
                           newFile.setAttribute("id", "FileUpload" + AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId);
                           newFile.setAttribute("name", "FileUpload" + AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId);
                           var div = document.createElement("div");
                           div.appendChild(newFile);
                           div.setAttribute("id", "div" + AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId);
                           fileUploadarea.appendChild(div);
                           AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId++;
                       }
                       </script>
```

and on code side

```
 if (templeupload.HasFile)
                {
                    TemplePhoto tempphoto = new TemplePhoto();
                    tempphoto.PhotoName = templeupload.FileName;
                    tempphoto.PhotoSize = templeupload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                    tempphoto.PhotoType = templeupload.PostedFile.ContentType;
                    tempphoto.ExtName = tempphoto.PhotoName.Substring(tempphoto.PhotoName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                    tempphoto.TempleID = ans;
                      HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
                      for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)

                      {
                                HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                                if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                                {
                    int id = new DBTemplePhoto().InsertData(tempphoto);
                    if (id != 0)
                    {
                                    hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/templepics/") + ans.ToString() + "." + tempphoto.ExtName);
                                    lblerror.Text = " File is Uploaded ";
                                }
                                     else
                    {
                        lblerror.Text = "Please check all the fields";
                    }
                            }
                      }
```

But it is uploading only one pic

Actually i want multiple image uploader just like gmail but i compromised with this one.
Can u please help me to solve the mistake in code to upload multiple image.
and if possible please tell the code to get  uploader like gmail

Comment: Seems to me this can be a browser issue. Can you tell me what browser you have used? I know that IE10 doesn't support multiple file upload...

Comment: what version of asp.net is being used? Are you doing the ctrl+selecting a file...to select multiple files?

Comment: i am using c# 4.0 and visual studio 2012 . yes i want exactly in which i select multiple pics by pressing ctrl

Answer (score 0):

Try add multipart/form-data to your form on server side:

```
this.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
```

Dont reuse "templeupload" properties, use only "HttpPostedFile hpf" properties from the loop.

For a better multiple file uploader, check JqueryFileUpload plugin:
https://github.com/i-e-b/jQueryFileUpload.Net

Answer (score 0):

Have the allow multiple file upload attribute set on the file upload control:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="templeupload" runat="server" CssClass="fileUpload" 
    AllowMultiple="true" />
```

On the server you have to iterate through the `PostedFiles` collection.

```
foreach(HttpPostedFile hpf in templeupload.PostedFiles)
{
    //do stuff with hpf
    hpf.SaveAs(...);
}
```